# jQuery function .toPrecision do not work into .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I solve problem. I have loaded data from JSON and when I want to manage format display of data using function `.toPrecision()` then function do not work. I think that restrictive is `.each()`. Why?

Any ideas for remove my problem? Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/others/files/jsonfile.json',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(data){
      $(data.MCNT_19).each(function(index, element){
        var varEfs1 = \$('#ajaxBerStatistics td.efs1');
        varEfs1.text(element[index+2]);
        var pom = varEfs1.text();          /* example: 35266 */
        alert(pom);             
          if (pom < 100000) { 
            pom.toPrecision(1); 
          } else { 
            alert('Is it wrong'); 
          }                    
        });
     });
   });
 timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });  
});
```

Comment: `toPrecision` _returns_ a string value, it does not change the value of the Number it is called on – your code _does_ nothing with that return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toPrecision` is a method of `Number` and not `String` so, you need to convert the string to `Number`.

Change this line `var pom = varEfs1.text();` to

```
var pom = +varEfs1.text(); // now pom is a number
```

And you should be storing the return value of `toPrecision` somewhere:

```
var newPom =  pom.toPrecision(1); // newPom contains modified number
```